# Display a form in two different ways

Tags: delphi

I display form in two different ways. The first one as a child of a tab sheet of page control like this:

```
myform := Tmyform.Create(<tab sheet of page control>);
myform.Parent := <tab sheet of page control>;
myform.Align := alClient;
myform.BorderStyle := bsNone;

myform.Visible := true;
```

This tab is always visible.

The second time I display it as a normal form like this:

```
myform := Tmyform.Create(nil);
myform.ShowModal;
```

I do this because I need to display the same form with some visual controls visible and in second time hidden.

My problem I noticed now the application consume more memory each time I open the form using the second method and if I used `action := cafree` in the close event I get access violation when I try to shutdown the application while the tab sheet is opened so how I should fix this without using two forms with same controls ?.

I use Delphi XE5

Comment: You should be able to do a `SavemyForm := myForm;` before the create, then a `myForm := SavemyForm;` after the modal form is freed

Comment: Or stop using the global `myForm` pointer to begin with.

Comment: Hard to diagnose what the problem is with the information here. As it stands I think the best we can do involves guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TForm` was never intended or designed to be embedded in other controls.  Use `TFrame` instead, it was specifically designed for this purpose.

```
var
  frame: TMyFrame;
begin
  frame := TMyFrame.Create(TheTabSheet);
  frame.Parent := TheTabSheet;
  frame.Align := alClient;
  frame.Visible := true;
end;
```

```
var
  form: TForm;
  frame: TMyFrame;
begin
  form := TForm.CreateNew(nil); // yes, a blank TForm
  try
    form.Width := ...;
    form.Height := ...;
    form.Caption := ...;
    frame := TMyFrame.Create(form);
    frame.Parent := form;
    frame.Align := alClient;
    frame.Visible := true;
    form.ShowModal;
  finally
    form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. What about dockable forms?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That is a whole different beast than simple embedding a `TForm` by setting its `Parent` property.  There is a whole framework involved in implementing the docking support.

Comment: Fundamentally though it revolves around doing exactly what you say was never intended to be done. I for one routinely embed forms as children of other windowed controls. It does work, and it is intended to work. The first sentence of your answer is wrong. Frames are a good option for sure, but I disagree with the claims you make in the text, and even the diagnosis of the problem. I routinely do what is described in the question with no problems.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: good for you. Feel free to share your experience.

Comment: That's a weak attitude. I already shared my experience in a constructive way. Feel free to correct your answer. And perhaps recognise that my input is not worthless. No need for such a contemptuous comment.